# While running PHP bin/magento deploy:mode:set production I am getting error on magento 2.1

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am using php7 with nginx

Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.

> Command returned non-zero exit code:
>   `/usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 1):

try to run the failing command with the `-vvv` switch (for very verbose output).

```
/usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

with this command you should at least get a better error message than "an error occurred..."

very likely, it's just the memory_limit being too low. You can increase the memory limit for a php process by adding the -d parameter to the php command:

```
/usr/bin/php7.0 -d memory_limit=1G -f /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

if you run deploy:mode:set production, the compilation will be startet as a sub process and you can't increase the memory limit like this (since the parameter is not passed to the sub command)

in this case, you have to increase the memory limit in your php configuration

Comment: So, did you execute the first command and get an actual error message? The 2nd was only an assumption. ..

Comment: Ahahaha now I can't deploy because magento uses the wrong PHP process when building this command and I don't have access to change the INI for that. Why the hell is there no other way to deploy without running a bunch of misconfigured subprocesses?

Answer (score 0):

```
Command returned non-zero exit code: /usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

In Magento 2 world, this error message is widely-known as memory limit problem. That is why in Magento 2 requirement, they recommend us to set

```
memory_limit = 768M
```

That is the perfect size to run Magento 2 commands in almost situation.

Comment: my limit in 1G memory imit