# I can't deploy production mode : Command returned non-zero exit code (magento 2.1)

Tags: php, deployment, magento2

I'm struggling with a big issue, the magento deployment command failed.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

return the following error:

Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/usr/bin/php7.0 -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR en_US`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394530/while-running-php-bin-magento-deploymodeset-production-i-am-getting-error-on-m

Comment: And this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9202

Comment: Hello Dalton, thank for your reply. the command :
php -i | grep memory_limit
return
memory_limit => 4096M => 4096M

Comment: Try to set the memory: `-d memory_limit=1G` , as explained in the first link.

Comment: I have the same error when I set memory to 1G as you explained

Comment: See the first answer of this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121231/magento-2-cant-switch-from-developer-to-production-command-returned-non-zero

Answer (score 18):

As stated in comments try setting your php memory limit higher what i do however is the following:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set --skip-compilation production
```

and then:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This way you should avoid the memory limit error and it works the same way as the deploy command is intended to only downside is 2 commands instead of one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer that @Anoxy posted.
It was kicked into production mode.

When I tried to run setup:di:compile after that, I got an error about a class in which I had called ::parent on Context.

That stopped compile from running, because Context doesn't have a parent that can be constructed.

I removed the parent call, and it ran